The fixture I would like to install would need to be offset but the ground and original wires are too short to reach the box.please help
I am seeing guidance. I would like to replace the existing fixture above the sink. The election placed it in the wrong place and I was so upset at the time I refused to let him come back and cut another hole in our custom cabinet. In the photo I wish to use the existing electrical box then hang the light from the chain over the center from where the light should have been. Can I tie onto the existing wiring and if so, is what I have purchased ok? Next, the ground wire is short how do I  remedy  that situation?






Welcome to SE! Please edit your post and using the mountains and moon icon, add your pictures so we can see what you see and help you.

The pictures of the fixture really don't help much. Take clear pictures of the electrical junction box where you want to hang the fixture.

Put in a new box that the fixture will attach to. Run wire between the old box and the new box, splicing the new wire to the Old wire in the old box. Put a cover on the old box, painting it to match the ceiling, since the connection must remain accessible. Mount the fixture on the new box.
Or, if there's an attic immediately above this so routing wire is relatively easy, you could run a new circuit from the switch directly to the new box.
Or, there's always my solution for a hanging fixture, which was to treat it as a swage lamp hanging from a hook screwed into a ceiling joist, with a lamp cord that runs across the ceiling, down a wall, and to an outlet.

Looks like the OP wants to hang this thing from the cabinet though, not the ceiling.  It's not clear how the existing fixture is mounted to the cabinet—what kind of box, if any, there is inside the cabinet.

Not to mention the lamp cord, which means there is probably an outlet in there somewhere rather than a hardwired connection.
